# Estimating set cardinality by querying

Tags: algorithm, math, probability, inequality

I have the following problem for homework and I was wondering if you could provide some hints.

---

Your friend has in mind a set of numbers S ⊆ {1, ... , n}. If you ask him about a set Q ⊆ {1, ..., n} he will answer whether the intersection S ∩ Q is empty or not. Your goal is to estimate (approximately) how many elements are contained in the set S.

Design a strategy to distinguish whether S contains ≤ k or ≥ (1 + ε)k for any k ∈ {1, . . , n}. Show that O (log(1/δ)/ε^2) queries are sufficient to distinguish the 2 cases with probability 1 - δ.

---

I think that by choosing a random set Q containing every element i ∈ {1, ..., n} with probability 1/k, then if S had at least k elements then the expected number of elements both in S and Q would be |S|/k. Then, if the intersection is empty we could say that (maybe with a good probability, I am not sure) that |S| < k. I think that I should run this experiment t times and have t random variables Xi, where Xi = 1 if the intersection is not empty, 0 otherwise. If the sum of Xi is at least t/2 then we could say that with some probability |S| < k. I am not sure if this is correct and which is the best approach to compute the probability. Moreover, I am not sure how to distinguish whether S contains ≤ k or ≥ (1 + ε)k elements.

How do you think that I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only get you started.

Suppose that your guess has a probability `p` of intersecting with your friend's set.  Then "did I intersect" is a random variable whose average value is `p`, and whose variance is `p * (1 - p)`.

If your guesses are independent from each other, then after `m` guesses the number that intersected will be a random variable with mean `p*m` and variance `m*p*(1-p)`.  If `m` is large, then by the Central Limit Theorem this random variable will follow approximately a normal distribution.  But we do not need such a strong result.  [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) gives us a bound for all `m`.

Now make your random sets such that if your friend's set had `(1 + ε/2)k` elements, then there would be even odds of getting a match.  If there are at most `k` elements then the probability of a match are less than 0.5 by an amount you can calculate.  If there are `(1 + ε)k` or more elements then the probability of a match will be more than 0.5 by an amount you can calculate.  So you'll just guess `m` times, count the matches, and compare to `m/2` to make your final conclusion.

The bounds that you get will not be tight, but they **should** wind up good enough to be able to answer your homework question.

Comment: I don't think Chebyshev is good enough here. A [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)) should work (use the looser, simpler inequalities).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I would have to do the homework to verify, but my suspicion is that Chebyshev is good enough.  Regardless, this approach is directionally right.